# Extracting Full Name from JSON string

Tags: json, json-query

I have a json string as shown in the example below, and I need to extract from it the Full Name of the  members.

I know I can extract each of them separately with

```
 $.members[*].lastName   and    $.members[*].firstName
```

but I can't seem to figure out how to get both of them together in one JSON query. i read about using the "," as a means but I couldn't figure out how for my specific case.

```
{
"group": "BLUE",
  "members": [
    {
       "memberId": "00081",
       "firstName": "JOHN",
       "lastName": "SMITH",
       "mail": "JSMITH@EXAMPLE.com"
    } ,
    {
       "memberId": "00081",
       "firstName": "JANE",
       "lastName": "DOE",
       "mail": "JDOE@EXAMPLE.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected result: [ John Smith, John Doe]

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated, I've never used JSON queries before.

Comment: Can you please specify which library are you using?

Comment: @RahulSharma I'm using an ETL tool called Talend and specifically using a component called tExtractJSONFields, so as to what library I don't know how to retrieve that information

Comment: can you define your own helper functions using this tool?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with over 10 hrs of attempts and research:

```
"$.members[*].['firstName','lastName']"
```

I did not know I had to use the '' .
Hope this helps someone else.